# How to add label name in default filter of Clarity Datagrid coloumn

Tags: vmware-clarity, clarity

```
  <clr-dg-column [clrDgField]="'subType'"> 
       {{subType}}
 </clr-dg-column>[enter image description here][1]
```

This code is creating a column in datagrid  using clarity. 
In image i want to add label name in this clarity default filter like Name: SubType

Is it possible or not. or how can i achieve it ?

Thanks

[See Image Of Datagrid Filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hPZk.png)

Comment: Can you post some code that shows what you are trying to do? I'm not sure what your goal is and an example of what you have tried so far would help me, help you. Here is a StackBlitz with the latest version of Clarity in it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-light-theme-v012-12ptd7

Comment: I have added a code in stackblitz. In code there is 1 column with default filter. I want. In default filter there should be a label name which shows the filter name like "Name: filter-by-datastore" and then filter textbox. Link for code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-light-theme-v012-aecbin

Comment: I see what you want now. No, its not possible to add a label to the column filter.